# This is what is written in the datapack function:

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=0}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -125 2.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=1}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -112 3 
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=2}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -125 11
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=3}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -112 12.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=5}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -68 3
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=6}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -55 2.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=7}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -68 12.5
execute if entity @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=8}] run tp @a ~ ~ ~ -55 11
```

`Tick.json` is performing the function every tick but instead of making the player look at the specified spots when a certain slot is in use, the player gets teleported to weird coordinates. Well now you might think that there is something wrong with the command, but long and behold the function works perfectly if I run it manually. The tick function is one I copied over from a 1.14.4 datapack, but the rest is a 1.15 datapack. Anyone got any clue on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The command is indeed wrong. You're executing at the whatever coordinates that the function is run from. If it's from an advancement or a command in chat, it would work, but if a command block does it, you get teleported to the command block and if it's run as a ticked function, it's undefined behaviour where it actually happens or whether it works at all.

The solution is probably to replace `if entity <selector>` with `as <selector> at @s` and `tp @a` with `tp @s`. But that might also not be what you want, you did not specify what exactly you want.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I did try 'execute at @a if entity...' but the same thing happened. I'll try using your suggestion, but I do not understand why running the function in chat is different from having it run by the datapack. All you do is essentially call for the function, but it shouldn't change who's running it, it should still be the datapack that calls it, or am I wrong here?

Comment: To clarify I am making a player stand still mid air then changing what the player is looking at depending on the hotbarslot selected. I can make it work with commandblocks and I can make it work with a function, but then running the function with a tick just does not work. Running the function with /function ... does what I am hoping for, but using the function with a tick it does something different.

Comment: I overlooked that you need both "as" AND "at". I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was playing around with 2 instances of the same function. Quickly figured out I would have to write it like this `execute at @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=0}] run execute as @a[scores={InShopMenu=1,PlayerSlot=0}] run tp @s ~ ~ ~ -125 2.5`